# Exporting Earth Engine results to kml for use in Google Earth

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth, google-earth-pro, google-earth-api

So I have a date range of MODIS temperature images that I am attempting to export from GEE for use in Google Earth. This is what the code looks like thus far:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MYD11A2')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-05-01', '2018-06-01'));
var landSurfaceTemperature = dataset.select('LST_Day_1km');
var landSurfaceTemperatureVis = {
  min: 14000.0,
  max: 16000.0,
  palette: [
    '040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
    '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
    '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
    'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
    'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
  ],
};
Map.setCenter(-85.60371794450282,44.73590436363271, 8);
Map.addLayer(
    landSurfaceTemperature, landSurfaceTemperatureVis,
    'Land Surface Temperature');

// Create a geometry representing an export region.
var features = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-85.1417893413635, 45.31413490213395, -86.125065708551, 44.65070625463291]);
```

Where I am having trouble is coding the export feature that would allow for an overlay to be placed into Google Earth. This is what I have now:

```
// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: dataset.filter('LST_Day_1km'),
  description: 'Overlay',
  scale: 30,
  region: features
});
```

So what do I need to add to that code to facilitate the export of the color-coded data set into a .kmz, GeoTIFF or some sort of file that could be overlayed in Google Earth? Do I need to .sum() the image set prior to export?

This is for personal use, so I do not need to embed it into a website, so I don't think I will need to use the API provided by Earth Engine....or do it?

EDIT:

After trying the below suggestion, this is what happened.

After I added the .mean() function, I could then export an image. Without that, I couldn't as I would get the error " Error: Invalid argument: 'image' must be of type Image."

I was able to successfully export a .tif that could be read in google earth when I added .mean()

```
Export.image.toDrive({ 
image: landSurfaceTemperature.mean(), 
description: 'Overlay', 
scale: 30, 
region: features });
```

However, the imported image was entirely white (no data or visualization.) I'm wondering if it has to do with exporting the landSurfaceTemperatureVis variable, however when attempting to export that variable I get an error saying that it's not a valid variable to export.

Any suggestions?

EDIT 2:

Still getting a white image upon importation to Google Earth.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the input dataset and scale in your export:

```
// Create a geometry representing an export region.
var features = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-85.1417893413635, 45.31413490213395, -86.125065708551, 44.65070625463291]);
Map.addLayer(features);
print("features",features);

// This function clips images to the ROI feature collection
var clipToCol = function(image){
  return image.clip(features);
};

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MYD11A2')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-05-01', '2018-06-01'))
                  .map(clipToCol);
print("dataset",dataset);
var landSurfaceTemperature = dataset.select('LST_Day_1km');
print("lST",landSurfaceTemperature);
var landSurfaceTemperatureVis = {
  min: 14000.0,
  max: 16000.0,
  palette: [
    '040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
    '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
    '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
    'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
    'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
  ],
};
Map.setCenter(-85.60371794450282,44.73590436363271, 8);
Map.addLayer(
    landSurfaceTemperature.filterDate("2018-05-01"), landSurfaceTemperatureVis,
    'Land Surface Temperature May 1');
Map.addLayer(
    landSurfaceTemperature.filterDate("2018-05-09"), landSurfaceTemperatureVis,
    'Land Surface Temperature May 9');
Map.addLayer(
    landSurfaceTemperature.filterDate("2018-05-17"), landSurfaceTemperatureVis,
    'Land Surface Temperature May 17');
Map.addLayer(
    landSurfaceTemperature.filterDate("2018-05-25"), landSurfaceTemperatureVis,
    'Land Surface Temperature May 25');
Map.addLayer(
    landSurfaceTemperature.mean(), landSurfaceTemperatureVis,
    'Land Surface Temperature Mean May');

// Where I am having trouble is coding the export feature that would allow for an overlay to be placed into Google Earth. This is what I have now:
print(landSurfaceTemperature.mean());
// Visualize image
var imageRGB = landSurfaceTemperature.mean().visualize(landSurfaceTemperatureVis);

print(imageRGB);
Map.addLayer(
  imageRGB)
// Export the image, specifying scale and region.

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: imageRGB,
  description: 'Overlay',
  scale: 1000,
  region: features
});
```

In R, you can then run

```
image(raster("OUTPUTIMAGE.tif"))
```

to verify that it worked.

Edit: To follow up, EarthEngine only exports images in TIFF and TFRecord formats, so you won't be able to export a kmz or something like that.  [But, you can open TIF's in Google Earth Pro anyway.](https://www.google.com/earth/outreach/learn/importing-geographic-information-systems-gis-data-in-google-earth/#importtiff)

Comment: I was able to successfully export a .tif that could be read in google earth when I added this:

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: landSurfaceTemperature.mean(),
  description: 'Overlay',
  scale: 30,
  region: features
});

the imported image was entirely white (no data or visualization.) I'm wondering if it has to do with exporting the landSurfaceTemperatureVis variable, however when attempting to export that variable I get an error saying that it's not a variable. 

Additionally, when I ran your code as is, i got " Error: Invalid argument: 'image' must be of type Image."

Comment: Your scale is set to 30 but MYD11A2 imagery is at 1000m resolution. That may be the problem. See updated answer.

Comment: Still getting a white overlay in GE. 

Also...pardon my ignorance, but when you say "In R, you can then run

"image(raster("OUTPUTIMAGE.tif"))", what does that mean? Where should I input that string?

Comment: Once you export image to drive in GEE (using "OUTPUTIMAGE.tif" or whatever it ends up being called), you can download it onto your computer. In R if you just navigate to your downloads folder using `setwd("path/to/directory")` you can load the image and display is using the raster package (`library(raster)`) with `image(raster("OUTPUTIMAGE.tif"))`. The Google Earth visualization is a separate issue from the GEE export.

Comment: Ok, updated code includes vizualization parameters so it works in Google Earth Pro. Checked on Macbook Pro.

Comment: [MRW when it works](https://i.imgur.com/hzGhr4Z.png)

Comment: Glad it works. Please mark as answered if the question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This was the final script:

```
// Create a geometry representing an export region.
var features = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-85.1417893413635, 45.31413490213395, -86.125065708551, 44.65070625463291]);
Map.addLayer(features);
print("features",features);

// This function clips images to the ROI feature collection
var clipToCol = function(image){
  return image.clip(features);
};

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MYD11A2')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-05-01', '2018-06-01'))
                  .map(clipToCol);
print("dataset",dataset);
var landSurfaceTemperature = dataset.select('LST_Day_1km');
print("lST",landSurfaceTemperature);
var landSurfaceTemperatureVis = {
  min: 14375.62,
  max: 15300.38,
  palette: [
    '040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
    '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
    '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
    'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
    'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
  ],
};
Map.setCenter(-85.60371794450282,44.93590436363271, 10);
Map.addLayer(
    landSurfaceTemperature.filterDate('2013-04-10', '2013-05-10'), landSurfaceTemperatureVis,
    'Land Surface Temperature 13');
Map.addLayer(
    landSurfaceTemperature.filterDate('2014-04-10', '2014-05-10'), landSurfaceTemperatureVis,
    'Land Surface Temperature 14');
Map.addLayer(
    landSurfaceTemperature.filterDate('2015-04-10', '2015-05-10'), landSurfaceTemperatureVis,
    'Land Surface Temperature 15');
Map.addLayer(
    landSurfaceTemperature.filterDate('2016-04-10', '2016-05-10'), landSurfaceTemperatureVis,
    'Land Surface Temperature 16');
Map.addLayer(
    landSurfaceTemperature.filterDate('2017-04-10', '2017-05-10'), landSurfaceTemperatureVis,
    'Land Surface Temperature 17');
Map.addLayer(
    landSurfaceTemperature.filterDate('2018-04-10', '2018-05-10'), landSurfaceTemperatureVis,
    'Land Surface Temperature 18');
Map.addLayer(
    landSurfaceTemperature.mean(), landSurfaceTemperatureVis,
    'Land Surface Temperature Mean May');

// Where I am having trouble is coding the export feature that would allow for an overlay to be placed into Google Earth. This is what I have now:
print(landSurfaceTemperature.mean());
// Visualize image
var imageRGB = landSurfaceTemperature.mean().visualize(landSurfaceTemperatureVis);

print(imageRGB);
Map.addLayer(
  imageRGB)
// Export the image, specifying scale and region.

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: imageRGB,
  description: 'Overlay',
  scale: 5,
  region: features,
  maxPixels: 400000000,
});
```